# How to add a background to text only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background image on top of which there is some text.
It is very hard to read the text because of the background.
I would like to add a white background just around the text itself, such that the text could be easily read. How can I accomplish this using CSS/Javascript/jQuery ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your text with a span:

```
<span class="white_bg">Your text here</span>
```

And put this in your CSS file:

```
.white_bg 
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 3px; /*add this if you want a bit of space around the text*/
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 7):

i have the text contained in a `<span> </span>` with background-color:White; or whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

I assume your background image is in a DIV or something... so you can nest the text inside.

For example... if you curently have:

```
<div>Some Text</div>
div{background:url(/path/to/image.png);}
```

You could change it to this:

```
<div><p>Some Text</p></div>
div{background:url(/path/to/image.png);}
div p{background:#fff;}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use text-shadow that is implemented by the newest web browsers:

```
<div style="background: url(some_image.jpg); text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; color: #fff">Readable</div>
```

or just do something like

```
<div style="background: url(some_image.jpg);"><p style="background: #fff">Readable</p></div>
```